# What's the meaning of this line of CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript

I was reading through the Journo's [source code](https://github.com/jashkenas/journo/blob/master/journo.litcoffee) and I stumbled upon this line of code:

```
markdown  = _.template(source.toString()) variables
```

What is `variables` doing here? Is `_.template(source.toString()) variables` valid stntax at all?

Here's the function wrapping that line of code:

```
Journo.render = (post, source) ->
      catchErrors ->
        do loadLayout
        source or= fs.readFileSync postPath post
        variables = renderVariables post
        markdown  = _.template(source.toString()) variables
        title     = detectTitle markdown
        content   = marked.parser marked.lexer markdown
        shared.layout _.extend variables, {title, content}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is valid. Parenthesis are optional (sometimes) in CoffeeScript when invoking a function, so it is taking the result of `template` and invoking it with arguments. It compiles to this JavaScript:

```
_.template(source.toString())(variables);
```

From the CoffeeScript [documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#language):

> You don't need to use parentheses to invoke a function if you're passing arguments. The implicit call wraps forward to the end of the line or block expression.

Comment: You should probably add that underscore's `template(source, object)` function *curries*; if you don't provide an object, you get back a function instead that takes an object and produces the templatized result.

Answer (score 1):

`_.template` compiles a template specified by `source.toString()`.  A template is a function, which is then called.  `variables` is a parameter for that function (just like `postPath post` are parameters for `fs.readFileSync`).

See also the docs for [_.template](http://underscorejs.org/#template)

Answer (score -1):

The question was nicely answered, but to help the OP with future coffee stunts, a great way to anser these koans is to

1. Go to the coffeescript.org site
2. Click on "Try coffeescript"
3. Cut/Paste the puzzle into the coffeescript section
4. Bingo! You see the generated javascript.

I admit to puzzling over coffeescript at times, and this is abs fab .. and saves headaches.